# Submit JSON Array of Objects with HTML Form

Tags: html, css, json

I've got the following HTML which submits JSON in the format below:

HTML:

```
<label for="renewal_date">Renewal Date</label><input type="text" name="custom_form_fields[renewal_date[value]" id="renewal_date" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[renewal_date[columns]]" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[renewal_date[content]]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[renewal_date[new_row]]" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[renewal_date[field_type]]" value="text">


<label for="hold_up">Hold Up</label><input type="checkbox" name="custom_form_fields[hold_up[value]" id="hold_up">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[hold_up[columns]]" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[hold_up[content]]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[hold_up[new_row]]" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[hold_up[field_type]]" value="check box">


<label for="to">To</label><input type="text" name="custom_form_fields[to[value]" id="to" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[to[columns]]" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[to[content]]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[to[new_row]]" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[to[field_type]]" value="text">

<label for="attention">Attention</label><input type="text" name="custom_form_fields[attention[value]" id="attention" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[attention[columns]]" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[attention[content]]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[attention[new_row]]" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_form_fields[attention[field_type]]" value="text">
```

JSON:

```
"custom_form_fields"=>
{
    "renewal_date"=>{"value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"4", "content"=>"","new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"},
    "hold_up"=>{"value"=>"on", "columns"=>"3", "content"=>"","new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"check box"},
    "to"=>{"value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"12", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"},
    "attention"=>{"value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"12", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"}
}
```

I want the JSON to format all the custom form field attributes as objects without the pointers like so:

```
 "custom_form_fields"=>
{
    {"name" => "renewal_date", "value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"4", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"},
    {"name" => "hold_up",  "value"=>"on", "columns"=>"3", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"check box"},
    {"name" => "to",  "value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"12", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"},
    {"name" => "attention",  "value"=>"asdc", "columns"=>"12", "content"=>"", "new_row"=>"false", "field_type"=>"text"}
}
```

I'm not sure how to format my HTML to produce this JSON. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to need some kind of script like JS or PHP to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with Regex. I just make the code :

> [regexr.com/47uol](https://regexr.com/47uol)

used this regex for match : `\n+[\s|\,]*(\"\w*")(\=\>)(\{)`

and replace by : 
`\n{"name" => $1,`